# convert datetime to date in proc-sql sas

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I'm trying to convert datetime22.3 variable to ddmmmyy10. in proc sql, this is giving me ****** in the output column.

How can I get the correct values in the output column?

Comment: can you elaborate more on your problem.Do you want to change date  format in SQL.

Comment: proc sql;

create table work.abc as
select 
DISTINCT  bd.Account_Id, 
BD.Billing_Dt /*Datetime22.3 */, 
from abc table; I want billing_dt to show date ddmmyy10. instead of dateitme.

Comment: use this function it will work `CONVERT(nvarchar(50),getdate(),103)`
Instead of `getDate()` put your column name in it. and for different format just change the number at the end of function . i.e. `101,102,103` like that so you will get different formats that you want
for more information on datetime format follow this link

[datetime](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp)

Comment: my slq is as below ---proc sql;

create table work.abc as
select 
DISTINCT  a.Account_Id, 
a.Billing_Dt format ddmmyy10. as Bill_date from abc table; I want billing_dt to show date ddmmyy10. instead of dateitme.

Comment: sorry, i was not clear in the beggning, i'm doing this SAS, so its proc sql, functions are different to sql server. thanks for comments. appriciate your effort to answer my question.

Answer (score 16):

You need to convert original SAS DATETIME value (think of it as data type) to SAS DATE value using `DATEPART()` function and apply appropriate format:

```
proc sql; 
 create table work.abc 
 as select DISTINCT a.Account_Id,
  DATEPART(a.Billing_Dt) format ddmmyy10. as Bill_date
from abc table;
quit;
```

Comment: That was on Spot i'm looking for, thanks very much vasja. really appriciate

Comment: Vasja, you might want to post this on the master duplicate as well - somehow it doesn't include the datepart answer as one of the possible ways to do this (among the several other examples).